# Setting WholeCellGroupOpener only for some cells

Tags: cells

If I set the value of `"WholeCellGroupOpener"` to `True`, the cell with "Input" CellStyle can be folded with a mouse click. I wonder if there is a way that we can set "WholeCellGroupOpener" only for cells that have "Section" or "Chapter" CellStyle, and not be working for "Input" CellStyle.

I've tried `"WholeCellGroupOpener" -> If[CellStyle[] != "Input", True, False]`, but it didn't work.

Comment: The `WholeCellGroupOpener` command [is not documented](https://reference.wolfram.com/search/?q=WholeCellGroupOpener).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WholeCellGroupOpener` can be set per cell, not only per whole notebook. Therefore, you can set it only to the cells you want by finding them with [`Cells`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cells.html).

```
SetOptions[#, WholeCellGroupOpener -> True] & /@ 
 Cells[CellStyle -> {"Chapter", "Section"}];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and modifications. It helps a lot! Still, I wonder if I can achieve the goal through "OptionsSetting" in "Format"? I have noticed that some options can be customized. Is "WholeCellGroupOpener" one of them?

Comment: I wouldn't know about that. But it doesn't seem like this is possible ...